# Como extrair dados do LinkedIn com python?

Tags: python, xml, rest

Galera, tudo bom? Então, eu to precisando de extrair algumas informações para uma pesquisa que faço na universidade e eu preciso extrair alguns dados de páginas do LinkedIn, eu estava extraindo com python utilizando expressões regulares, mas para extrair algumas coisas tava muito difícil de achar algum padrão pra eu poder utilizar expressões regulares, só que eu sei que tem como extrair diretamente o xml da página do linkedIn, se não me engano o próprio linkedIn tem uma api, chamada rest api, alguém sabe **como** usá-la ou **como** fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para usar uma API desse tipo, basta realizar o cadastro do seu APP no [LinkedIn developers](https://developer.linkedin.com/) e criar um script que realize requisições http para obter os dados do site ([Mais detalhes na própria documentação](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)).

Felizmente, existe um módulo python que funciona como uma camada de abstração, que nos permite economizar tempo evitando codar os scripts de requisições novamente. O nome do módulo é [python-LinkedIn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin/4.0), e está disponível para download através do pip.

#Exemplo da documentação oficial

```py
from linkedin import linkedin 

API_KEY = "wFNJekVpDCJtRPFX812pQsJee-gt0zO4X5XmG6wcfSOSlLocxodAXNMbl0_hw3Vl" 

API_SECRET = "daJDa6_8UcnGMw1yuq9TjoO_PMKukXMo8vEMo7Qv5J-G3SPgrAV0FqFCd0TNjQyG"

RETURN_URL = "http://localhost:8000"

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

print(authentication.authorization_url) 

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

Os valores que devem ir nas variáveis API_SECRET e API_KEY são lhe informados assim que realizar o cadastro do seu APP (São valores únicos e devem ser usados apenas por você em um projeto específico).